# Help me to simulate this DIAC-TRIAC circuit

Tags: power-electronics, triac, diac

I was given to simulate the circuit in the lab. The picture of the circuit from the manual is given below.
[image: Diagram from the manual.]

I made the same circuit in LTspice.
[image: Implementation in LTspice]

The problem is that I do not get the expected output as you can see here.
[image: Output]
I was supposed to get a chopped-off sine waveform. Instead, I get this sine waveform which is in the mV range(peak to peak). What am I doing wrong here?
Please help me.

Comment: There is always zero gate current into U2 in your circuit.

Comment: How to solve this issue?
The given manual doesn't specify this. Also, the course tutor started the lab before teaching the theories. 
Please, help.

Comment: Ask yourself how current can possibly flow into the gate.

Comment: I think that by turning on the DIAC I can flow current through the gate. Then why isn't my DIAC turning on?

Comment: As drawn, zero current can flow into the gate.  Hint: V1 and V2 are completely isolated in LTspice - but is this the case in reality?

Comment: Current needs a circuit to flow through.

Comment: I added the -ve terminal of the V2 to the ground. Now I am getting a very short pulse of the voltage.

Comment: The circuit from the manual is not working, so your simulation is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, diac is supplied with main voltage.

Here an example of "firing" an SCR with such topology (Diac, R-C).

[image]

With a battery, it would be a "little" different, if wired correctly ...
Note also that a minimum value resistor is needed ... for safety of devices.